# Python tutorials for Actionlib?

Tags: ros-kinetic, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there python versions of the instructions for the various tutorials for ActionLib? I think I found the .py source code (that looks like the counterpart to the C++ version) but no instructions. Is that true?

For example: http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281077/python-tutorials-for-actionlib?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The listing on [wiki/actionlib_tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials) (section *Beginner Tutorials*) links to 2 Python versions of the C++ tutorials for me:

- "Writing a Simple Action Server using the Execute Callback (Python)"
- "Writing a Simple Action Client (Python)"

The advanced tutorials do not seem to have Python variants available.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-29**:
yeah check this link http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20%28Python%29